# check if is digit

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I have a routine that convert a number to ASCII. The problem is the digit-checking,isn't working.

```
.loop1: 
    xor edx,edx ;0
    mov ebx,10  ;divisor    
    div ebx      ;eax = eax/ebx 
    add edx,48   ;eax += 48 

    cmp edx,'0' ;if(edx < '0')      
    jl error    ; error()       
    cmp edx,'9' ;if(edx > '9')      
    jg error    ;error()        

    push edx    ;put value into STACK   
    add esi,1       
    test eax,eax    
    jz loop2
    jmp loop1
```

The problem is:

```
    cmp edx,'0'     
    jl error        
    cmp edx,'9'     
    jg error
```

Even for `mov eax,msg` where  `msg` is `msg db "abc"` the code will not to `error` routine.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The remainder from unsigned division by 10 is never going to be less than 0 or greater than 9, so those `jl` and `jg` instructions are never going to jump to `error`.

Comment: But there is a `add edx,48`. If non-digit is seen,this values may be greater than '9',right?

Comment: Do the math... '0'=48,...,'9'=57. So, whether you compare the remainder directly with 0...9 or first add 48 and then compare the sum with 48...57, the result is not going to change.